# Filter a list inside an observablecollection

Tags: wpf, linq, filter

How to filter a list inside an observablecollection with the following code:

```
Addresses.Repopulate((Repository.Addresses).Where(x => x.Types.));
```

Types can only contain id 7 or id 8.

Any Idea's?

Greets

Solution:

```
Addresses.Repopulate(Repository.Addresses.Where(x => x.Types.Any(y => y.Id == 7 || y.Id ==     8)));
```

Comment: Most people would approach this by attaching a filter to the underlying ListCollectionView.  Is there a reason you can't do that also?

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, then please add your solution into an answer and tick it as the correct answer. I think you could do with reading through the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page for this website.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your problem, but how about this?:

```
Addresses.Repopulate((Repository.Addresses).Select(x => x.Types).
    Where(t => t.Id == 7 || t.Id == 8);
```

Maybe if you provide more information about your class structure(s) and exactly what you want, we can provide better answers?